# I don't understand the main class

Tags: java

I've been using BlueJ to learn programming with Java, using the book "Objects First with Java" by David Barnes and Michael Kolling. I've found some practice problems that I can't seem to get to work in non-BlueJ compilers. For example, the code throws errors in Eclipse.

I create a new class for every problem the "solve" the problem in. If I do it in BlueJ it works fine but I can't run it in Eclipse or any other sites without problems.

Example is this code that should return the grade for a teacher.

```
 public class Problem1 {

 public void betyg(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int rätt){
     if(rätt >= a) System.out.println( "A");
     if(rätt < a && rätt >= b) System.out.println( "B");
     if(rätt < b && rätt >= c) System.out.println( "C");
     if(rätt < c && rätt >= d) System.out.println( "D");
     if(rätt < d && rätt >= e) System.out.println( "E");
     else System.out.println( "F");
 }

}
```

when I run it in Eclipse nothing even happens. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
This is the other class I have in my project. 
I understand that I need this in order for it to work because this is the "starting point" of my program. But how do I get it to run my "Problem1" class and its method "betyg"?

```
 public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Problem1 test1 = new Problem1();        
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to have one.

Comment: The `main` method (not class) is the first method run. If you don't have one, the program doesn't run.

Comment: Can you print your whole code? You are defining a class, so you probably only need to call `new Problem1().betyg(arguments);` from your main

Comment: You have two books about Java and none of them contains at least one example of a main method?

Comment: Check out [A closer look into a "Hello World" application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/). More specifically, scroll down to "The main method" section - **every application must contain a main method whose signature is:
`public static void main(String[] args)`**

Comment: **I don't see why this is being downvoted.** This is a beginners question that shows a lack of understanding, sure, but it's also a valid one that shows legitimate confusion.

Comment: The tooltip for downvotes starts with "_This question does not show any research effort_". I don't see much research effort in this question.

Comment: @berry120 It's being downvoted due to lack of effort. You could go just about anywhere to find out about the main method now-a-days. There are many questions similar to this one on this site already

Comment: `test1.betyg(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);` Change the `0`s to the numbers you want. Add this line after you create `test1`.

Comment: @Patrick Thank you that works. I'll try some different things with it to see how it works and learn  :)

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times, and is a dupe.  However, it's my nap time so I'm not going to look up a reference just now.

Answer (score 1):

BlueJ can instantiate any arbitrary objects and run any methods on them - it's a novice IDE designed to help you get started.

Eclipse, Netbeans et al. require a proper "Main class", that is a class with a method with the *exact* signature:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Problem1 p = new Problem1();
    //Any other code here
}
```

If the class doesn't have that (as this one doesn't), it's not a main class and won't be treated as such.

Comment: Okey. I understand that I need the "Main class". But how do I use the Main Class to call on my method to do the grading?

Comment: You can instantiate and call methods on objects from within the main method (see updated answer.)